# MEAN Mongodb replace collection and create documents

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean

So i have a schema like that:

```
var article = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    comments : [{
        pe: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment'
    }]
});
```

and:

```
var comment = new mongoose.Schema({
    created : Date,
    text : String
});
```

now i have my small angular application, when i retrieve with my API and article i get something like:

```
{
    title : "please help me"
    comments : []
}
```

now on the front end I push some comments and the new object is:

```
{
    title : "please help me"
    comments : [{
        text : "Now, go f**k yourself",
        date : "1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC."
    }]
}
```

when i call the API and I update the document, I would like that mongo would Create the sub-object comments by himself, is there a way ?
Should it do it automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I would write a article schema this way (disclaimer: I haven't tried mongoose):

```
var article = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String  // or mongodb.ObjectId? I'm not sure.
    title : String,
    comments : [{
        _id: String    // this field is not nessesary
        text: String,
        date: String
    }]
});

var comment = new mongoose.Schema({
    created : Date,      // created or date?
    text : String
});
```

When you retrieve with you api, you'll get something like:

```
{
  "_id": "ndrjgnd..fesf",
  "title": "grdgrdgr",
  comments: [ {"text": "hello", "created": "2016:...:"}, ... , ] 
}
```

Then you can push new comments from front end:

```
{
  "articleId": "ndrjgnd..fesf",     // this is important.
  "text": "balabala"
}
```

And update db:   `db.article.update( {_id: ariticleId}, {$push: newComment})`

Comment: True, is that I tried to simplify the structure in the example.
In my app the object comment has a complex structure and I prefer to have it separately in another schema because i should able to query it.

Comment: @GaetanoPessa so, what's the problem

Comment: I'm not an expert, the idea is that if a I try to save in the DB a json object with an array inside (the array that contains the comment), of object that has a structure like the one in the schema, mongo should automatically recognize is a comment and create my comment Object.
This doesnt happen. Is it normal ?

Comment: @GaetanoPessa mongo knows nothing about your schema. You get what you have put into mongo. IMO, mongo doesn't do well with relational data. Neither storing comment object or comment references inside article is a good idea. The query statement is more complicate than that in conventional databases.

Comment: dow... so how you store relational  data in mongo?

Comment: I prefer storing comment object ids in article. Maybe you can find some projects that use mongodb. @GaetanoPessa

Comment: yes, now I'm doing the same but i still quite annoying.
I mean if I delete an article, from what I understood, I need to manually delete the comments contained inside.
Same, if i create an article, and I create it with some comment inside, I need to manually create the comments.

Comment: @GaetanoPessa yes, and that's non relational database

Comment: ok, I'm sorry if my question are sometimes stupid...  I'll try to find some example about how to structure my DB with mongo

Comment: @GaetanoPessa tell me when you find it. I'd like to know it too.